# nmake makefile is not using inference rule

Tags: c, makefile, implicit, nmake, inference

I am trying to get a target's object dependencies to use the inference/implicit rule.  I get this error instead

> NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'interface1.obj'
>   Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2' Stop.

the last target to be called is

```
interface.dll: interface1.obj interface2.obj
```

I have inference rules in the makefile like this

```
.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp .obj

.c.obj:
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

.cpp.obj:
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

I have tried echoing tests after .c.obj is called and it never even gets there.  It seems to not recognize the rules when trying to make the interface.obj
I have also tried making the rule with paths like this

```
{$(SOURCE_DIR)}.c{$(BIN_PATH)}.obj:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
```

I have succeeded in making a interface1.obj target and compiling the files one at a time, but I can't get the inference/implicit rule to get recognized and used.

Comment: Please post a minimal example that results in this exact error, where's the recipe containing `cd` for instance?

Answer (score 2):

```
{$(SOURCE_DIR)}.c{$(BIN_PATH)}.obj:
```

means the object you are trying to make `interface1.obj` is located in `$(BIN_PATH)`.
If you list your objects as `interface1.obj` then it will assume `interface1.obj` is in the current directory.

So you need to write the dependent object files as such: `$(BIN_PATH)\\interface1.obj`

vice versa, you could write the rule like `{$(SOURCE_DIR)}.c{}.obj:` and your dependent object like `interface1.obj` if they were indeed in the current directory.

same goes for the source files.

-Kelsey